# Would a question about where to report a contractor's behavior be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I have the following question:

> Subj: Where would I report bad contractor behavior?
>
> A contractor in my area is asking for 50% of the quoted price for the work as cash up front with a promise to come back in two weeks to do the work. He also refuses to provide a contract for the work he’s being offered to perform.
>
> Should I report this behavior to a civil organization? Who do I report to? Sheriff? Police? Tax office?

---

I realize that https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says

> Legal questions, including contracts with builders, contractor negotiation, and rental agreements.

but this feels more like civil responsibility and less of a rant or a legal question.

Is there a better site on the network to ask this question?

I hate to clog up the pipes with a bad/dumb question so I figured I would start at meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wouldn't be a good question for the site. It's not about how to improve your home, rather it's about how to take potentially legal action against a contractor. The answer depends on where you live and I don't know of any SE site where it would be on topic.

Comment: Yeah, I just feel like ethics is important too. I agree that jurisdiction changes based on location, so in one place you talk to the Sheriff, in another the Tax Office, etc. Would be nice if there was a great place/process/advice to figure out how to/if you should report this sort of thing.

Comment: You may talk to your state's licensing authority. If nothing else, they may be able to point you in a better direction for your particular area.